# WordPress get custom post type categories

Tags: wordpress

**Hello**

I need to get custom post type categories in WordPress.

For example, if I have post type "movies" and I have "movie 1" and "movie 1" has 3 categories like cat1 (cat_ID = 10), cat2 (cat_ID = 11), and cat3 (cat_ID = 13). I need to display, in my single-movies, all 3 categories (with their links).

categories: cat1, cat2, cat3.

And, if I want to exclude 1 or more categories in my page, I need it also.
for example `echo movie_categories(exclude=11,13)`: the result will be:
categories: cat1.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set multiple categories in the arguments of you WP_Query.

`new WP_Query('cat=10,11,13')`

Example:

```
<?php
  $allcategories = new WP_Query('cat=10,11,13');
  if ( $allcategories->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $allcategories->have_posts() ) : 
      $allcategories->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hello
this is not what i needed, i dont need query that display my post from category.
when i in the post page i need do display all his categories.